# Equivalent statements with one very difficult direction

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, logic, equivalence-relations

This may have been asked already but I am lacking keywords probably.

I am looking for examples of proven equivalences $A \Leftrightarrow B$ where one direction, say $A \Rightarrow B$, is very difficult compared to the other direction.

To avoid trivial examples, I am requiring that neither $A$ and $B$ are definitions (or easy restatements of definitions).

The example can be research level, in particular in number theory, algebra and functional analysis.

Comment: When I am faced with proving an equivalence, my expectation is that one direction will be easy and the other direction will be hard. I challenge you to come up with examples where this is not the case.

Comment: Interesting remark, I'll ponder it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have an example. Suppose $a,b,c \in \mathbb N, gcd(a,b)=1, a^2+b^2=c^2\iff \exists m,n \in \mathbb N,  a=2mn, b=m^2-n^2, c=m^2+n^2$

One direction is easy.

$a^2+b^2=c^2 \implies (2mn)^2 +(m^2-n^2)^2=m^4-2m^2n^2+n^4+4m^2n^2=m^4+2m^2n^2+n^4=(m^2+n^2)^2$. So given $m$ and $n$ ,we necessarily have a primitive Pythagorean tripe.

How do you get your $m$ and $n$ given an arbitrary primitive triple?

$gcd(a,b)=1 \implies$ they aren't both even. They can't both be odd since the sum of the square of two odd numbers is never a perfect square.

WLOG $a$ is even, $b$ is odd $\implies c$ is odd.

$a^2=c^2-b^2=(c-b)(c+b)$

Now $g(b,c)=1$ for otherwise $gcd(a,b)>1$ which is not allowed. $(c-b)$ and $(c+b)$ are both even, but their halfs are relatively prime, i.e. gcd ([c-b]/2, [c+b]/2)=1. else we would have $gdcd(b,c)>1$

Sincd LHS is perfect square, so is RHS. This suggests $c-b=2n^2$ and $c+b=2m^2$ for some  positive integers $m$ and $n$.

So $a^2=4m^2n^2\implies a=2mn, b=(2m^2-2n^2)/2=m^2-n^2$. By similar arguments $c=m^2+n^2$.

Comment: Thank you, that's nice example indeed : a parametrization of a very natural set.

Comment: Please don't duplicate common proofs. Of course  this common proof already occurs here *many* times. Note that the (too broad) question does not ask for proofs.